# Valores em C não retornam o que é esperado

Tags: c, int

Estou em estudos pessoais seguindo uma apostila que esse algoritmo dá o seguinte resultado:

#### Algoritmo da Apostila

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main() {

   int n = 10;
   int m = ++n;
    printf("\n N=%d M=%d",n,m);

   int a = 10;
   int x = a++;
    printf("\n A=%d, X=%d",a,x);

}
```

O resultado sai esse valor:

```
N = 11 M= 11 
A=11 X=10
```

Sendo que o valor que colocaram na apostila foi:

```
N=10 M=11
A=10 X=10
```

O que houve de errado?
Não consegui o resultado que colocaram na apostila... Sendo que o meu algoritmo está idêntico ao da apostila.

Comment: link da apostila: https://www.apostilando.com/apostila/3353/apostila-de-estrutura-de-dados-completa-150-paginas Página que está o algoritmo é a 28-29 da apostila.

Comment: Acredito que a apostila esteja errada, a prefixada incrementa primeiro o n depois manda pra m, já a pós-fixada manda o valor de a pra x primeiro, depois incrementa a

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado @Four

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso ocorre por causa dessas duas linhas `int m = ++n;` e `int x = a++;` que além de `m` e `x` estarem recebendo o valor `n` e `a`, o valor de `n` e `a` estão sendo somados a mais 1. Então o valor de `n` e `a` que eram 10 vai para 11. Mas tem outro fator ai, o **pré-incremento** e **pós-incremento**.

No pré-incremento os `++` vem antes da variável `int m = ++n;` desse modo ao executar o valor de `n` sera somado a 1 indo para 11 e logo após a variável `m` recebe o valor `n` indo para 11.

No pós-incremento os `++` vem depois da variável `int x = a++;` desse modo ao executar a variável `x` recebera o valor de `a` indo para 10 e após o valor de `a` sera somado a 1 indo para 11.

Answer (score 0):

Se o código estiver assim na apostila com esse resultado a apostila colocou o resultado errado, se modificar um pouco como coloquei temos esse resultado que ainda não bate com  o da apostila.

**resultado:**

```
N=10 M=11

A=11, X=10
```

**codigo:**

```
include stdio.h
include conio.h

main() {
    int m = 10;
    int n = m++;

    printf("\n N=%d M=%d",n,m);

    int a = 10;
    int x = a++;

    printf("\n A=%d, X=%d",a,x);
}
```