# Função em C não retorna o número ao quadrado que o usuario computou

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Estou aprendendo C e estrutura de dados, estou usando uma apostila (https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=https://api.apostilando.com/pdf-viewer.php?pdf%3D3353_estrutura_dados.pdf), eu acho que estou tendo problemas nessa apostila ou não estou entendendo o conteúdo muito bem, pois esse é o 2º algoritmo que tento fazer e não bate com o da apostila...

**Algoritmo**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {

    int num;
    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    sqr(num); /*sqr recebe “num” do programa principal*/
}

    sqr() {
        int x;/* x é um “parâmetro” recebido do programa principal
              no caso x “vale” o conteúdo de num */
        printf("%d ao quadrado e: %d", x, x*x);
    }
```

O problema é que ele não retorna o número que o usuário colocou e nem ele ao quadrado, aliás, até retorna mais o resultado esperado não sai como deveria.

**Resultado**

```
Digite um numero: 10
4214871 ao quadrado e: 1152810385
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.278 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Edit: Já tinha feito um algoritmo que não tinha dado certo e tinha postado aqui ([Valores em C não retornam o que é esperado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/375027/valores-em-c-n%C3%A3o-retornam-o-que-%C3%A9-esperado))

Edit2: Achei uma outra apostila em C, é boa? (http://www.joinville.udesc.br/portal/professores/fiorese/materiais/apostilaC_Univ_Fed_Uberlandia.pdf), meu único medo é ela não retratar muito a fundo sobre estrutura de dados.

PS: Se puderem me recomendar alguma apostila sobre estrutura de dados para meu aprendizado em C para depois iniciar com outras linguagens, agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está passando o número por parâmetro:

```
sqr(num);
```

Mas sua função `sqr` não possui o parâmetro, ela está assim:

```
void sqr () { ... }
```

E deveria ser da seguinte forma:

```
void sqr (int x) { ... }
```

O valor que aparece no seu resultado é o valor de `x` que você criou dentro de `sqr`, onde você criou mas não atribuiu nenhum valor:

```
    void sqr() {
        int x; 

        /* esse X não está recebendo nenhum valor */

        printf("%d ao quadrado e: %d", x, x*x);
    }
```

Comment: Deu certo! Valeu Thiago, mas eles não tinham mencionado nada do void na apostila... como pode ver na página 39/152... Além do mais, queria saber tem alguma outra apostila que me recomende, pois essa parece que está meio incompleto.

Comment: @Devprogramacao o código dessa apostila é duvidoso, pois também gera um warning na declaração da função `main()`. [Link para o Código corrigido](https://repl.it/repls/WhimsicalWaryBrain)

Comment: @AugustoVasques tem alguma que me recomende? Para não gerar discussões longas, só enviar o link da apostila (as).

Comment: http://www.joinville.udesc.br/portal/professores/fiorese/materiais/apostilaC_Univ_Fed_Uberlandia.pdf

Comment: Desculpa cara. Nunca li uma apostila na minha vida, mas recomendo o livro C For Dummies.